# How to use box cursor in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have developed console like application on Android 9.0.
I want to use box shape cursor in EditText. Is there way to change cursor shape?

I want to be change cursor shape like following:

[image]

How I can change cursor shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/mycursor"`  in your edittext and create shape like this :

**mycursor.xml:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
        <size android:width="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/> 
    </shape>
```